# Linux bash shell copy previous lines (not history) with keyboard

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to use the keyboard in order to select some text in the terminal windows that is not in the currently edited line? (for example, in order to copy part of previous command output).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, neither of the "big three" terminal emulators can do that, but both `screen` and `tmux` offer a scrollback buffer you can access via keyboard.

### GNU screen

`screen`'s <kbd>Prefix</kbd> key is <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> per default, but all of that is customizable, so with a default config:

1. Enter copy mode with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>.
2. Move cursor around with `vi` motions: <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>,  <kbd>/</kbd>,  <kbd>?</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> all work (see `man screen` under `copy` for more info on key bindings).
3. Start selecting with <kbd>Space</kbd>, move around, and stop selecting with <kbd>Space</kbd> again. This will leave copy mode.
4. Paste the selected text with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>.

### tmux

`tmux` behaves pretty much the same, except it uses some different keys per default:

1. Enter copy mode with <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>.
2. Move cursor around with <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDown</kbd> etc. (see `man tmux | less -p '^WINDOWS AND PANES'` for the list of copy-mode bindings).
3. Start selecting with <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>, move around, and stop selecting with <kbd>Meta+w</kbd>. This will leave copy mode.
4. Paste the selected text with <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the terminal you use. It is possible in shell mode in [`emacs`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

Comment: I am using gnome-terminal, do you know if it is somehow possible?

Comment: @Itay Nope. I use mouse :)

Comment: Thanks, the mouse slows me down :) but I guess I'll have to live with it :)

Comment: @Itay - While you still have to use the mouse to select, you can use `Ctrl+Shift+C` to actually make the copy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite what you're asking, but if you redirect output through xclip, you can pull it from the clipboard and edit it.  I never thought about using it to minimize keyboard use.

```
$ echo "this is the primary buffer" | xclip -selection "primary"
$ cat << EOF > primary.txt
> this is the primary buffer
> EOF
```

Under gnome-terminal, I can use shift-insert to paste into the here-file.  From the man page xclip -selection "clipboard" does the real clipboard instead of the x buffer.

I can't seem to get it working with tee though... hmmm....  that's kind of important.